# Format of citations in footnotes in Office365 Word

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, footnote, citations

I want citations in footnotes to look similar to the way they appear as bibliography entries.  For example, I want a citation to look like this:

1. BRUIJN, J. R.; GAASTRA, F. S.; SCHÖFFER, I., Dutch-Asiatic Shipping in the Seventeenth and Eighteenth Century, 1987

NOT LIKE THIS:

1. (BRUIJN, GAASTRA and SCHÖFFER 1987)

I know this can be accomplished manually, but is there a way to change the format of the citation in a footnote so everything can be accomplished automatically?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the reason for putting the citations in the footnote instead of the bibliography? In Word, you always have a (shortened) citation reference and then in the bibliography you have the full citation details. What you are trying to achieve, is basically putting the full citation where the shortened one belongs. There is not an easy automatic way to do this in Word.

Comment: It is a standard way of referencing when writing a PhD thesis or a book - the citation goes into the footnote (or endnote) as well as into the biliography.  In the footnote (or endnote) you also add the page number or other specific details that a reader can use to retrieve the reference.  I have since learned that MS Word is not a suitable platform  for writing a book.  You need to third party add-on like https://endnote.com/?language=en to get this functionality.  Endnote also allows you to group your bibiography by type of reference - very nifty...

Comment: Just as an observation, the content and formatting of a citation are defined in the XSLT stylesheet associated with the bibliographic style you are using. Windows Desktop Word only allows *one* such format for Citations and one for the Bibliography. You can't "invent" another one that Word would use when the citation is in a footnote. That said, at one point, Mac Word did support a separate footnote citation format (probably in Mac Word 2011, I forget), but in the 2015/2016 version which tried to align the Windows and Mac versions more closely, that was dropped.